# How To set up SCP from localhost to remote Ubuntu server - Part 2

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, scp

I am trying to configure an ubuntu vps. I have set up ssh secure login using rsa public and private keys from a local machine.

As well as disabling root login I have also set up iptables and configured to allow ports 80 and 22 (port 22 only from my ip address) for the ssh tunnel.

I can connect fine using ssh but when I try using scp from my local machine

```
sudo scp /var/www/filetocopy user@remoteaddress:/var/www/filetocopy
```

I get this error

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have added the -v to display the output

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host ip.add.re.ss, user username, command scp -v -t -- /var/www/filetocopy
OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ip.add.re.ss [ip.add.re.ss] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA b5:ea:fe:e6:07:a9:a6:3e:d2:6f:2d:3f:86:55:04:5f
debug1: Host 'ip.add.re.ss' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

Thanks again for the help so far

Comment: Have you disabled password authentication ? The local user you are using when running sudo, is root. Therefore, if you uploaded your user's private key (instead of root's) the key won't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can get the same result as you is if I remove the the `authorized_keys` from the remote host. Check that the public key in `user@remoteaddress:~/.ssh/authorized_keys` matches the identity file for the user on the local machine.